# how to list all python test scripts that contain "def test"

Tags: grep, find

Want  to list all python test scripts  that contain  "def test"

This command line did not work while individual command works

```
find . -name "*.py" | grep "def test"
```

Comment: Perhaps `find -name \*.py -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'def test`?

Comment: All the answers so far will find hits when `def test` is used inside a string or comment. Is this really what you want? Avoiding it is possible but substantially more complex (it essentially requires *parsing* the Python files, for which Python has a dedicated module).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find and echo file names only with pattern found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342008/find-and-echo-file-names-only-with-pattern-found), [How to list .txt files with specific content?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/425344/22142) and about a dozen others...

Comment: The first part `find . -name "*.py"` finds the *filenames*, so your `grep "def test"` finds only file name matches. To amend your example use `xargs` as pr the answer by @roel-schroeven below.

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
grep -r --include '*.py' 'def test'
```

- `-r` tells grep to search for files recursively
- `--include '*.py'` tells grep to only examine files whose names end in `.py`.

The `--include` option is supported by both [GNU (Linux) grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) and [MacOS grep](https://ss64.com/osx/grep.html)

#### Discussion of pipeline approach

In the following command, find passes the names of the files found to standard input of grep:

```
find . -name "*.py" | grep "def test"
```

The issue here is that grep treats its standard input as the text to search.  Consequently, the only output will be those files whose *name* (as opposed to contents) contains `def test`.

For example, let's create an empty file:

```
$ touch 'def test.py'
```

And run the pipeline command:

```
$ find . -name "*.py" | grep "def test"
./def test.py
```

The command finds this file because of its name.  Its contents are never examined.

Comment: ... if your `grep` supports `--include` like GNU grep does.

Answer (score 11):

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec grep -l 'def test' {} \;
```

or

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec grep -l 'def test' {} +
```

The second version will result in fewer invocations of `grep` by specifying sets of files as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -ril 'def test' .
```

The above command would list what you are looking.

In the command 
- the options ril refer to recursive(r) case insensitive(i) search and list(l) only file names

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to execute a command on files found by `find` is using xargs:

```
find . -name "*.py" | xargs grep "def test"
```

In case of grep, you can use recursive grep instead of find + grep as other answers have explained, but xargs is good to know because it's a general approach that can be used for other use cases too.

(And as Doug O'Neal commented: if there are filenames with spaces, you have to tell find and xargs to use null characters as terminators: `find . -name "*.py" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "def test"`)

Comment: With some regex you can avoid commented code - `grep "^[^#]*def test"`, or where the line *begins* with the search term - `grep "^def test"`. Your answer though was short and sweet and to the point.